# Mediawiki Rewrite to external site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mediawiki

I am moving my site from Mediawiki to Wordpress and would like to redirect this page:

http://wecheck.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz

to this page:

http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/

Currently in .htaccess I have

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=Aaron_Swartz$
RewriteRule ^/w/index\.php$ http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/? [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

The second part makes the pretty URLs for mediawiki. I have tried many, many variations but I can't get it to work at all. Any help most appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Log file using the solution given. What is the .phtml?

```
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000]  init rewrite engine with requested uri /wiki/Aaron_Swartz
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (1) pass through /wiki/Aaron_Swartz
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/w/wiki.phtml
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (3) [perdir /var/www/] add path info postfix: /var/www/w/wiki.phtml -> /var/www/w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz -> w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^wiki/Aaron_Swartz$' to uri 'w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz'
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (3) [perdir /var/www/] add path info postfix: /var/www/w/wiki.phtml -> /var/www/w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz -> w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^w/index\.php$' to uri 'w/wiki.phtml/Aaron_Swartz'
[24/Jan/2013:22:01:00 +0000] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/w/wiki.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Apache directives like `RewriteRule` are applied before MediaWiki even sees the request.  Thus, your current rule should work for http://wecheck.org/w/index.php?title=Aaron_Swartz, but not for http://wecheck.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz.

Actually, though, the rule won't work because your regexp begins with a `/`, but in .htaccess context the leading slash (or whatever you've set [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) to) is removed before the rewrite rules are applied.

Thus, fixing those two problems, what you need is something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# match the short URL of the page:
RewriteRule ^wiki/Aaron_Swartz$ http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/ [R=301,L]

# optional: also match the long version of the URL:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=Aaron_Swartz$
RewriteRule ^w/index\.php$ http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/ [R=301,L]
```

---

**Edit:** Based on your log file, it looks like you have a `wiki.phtml` file in your webserver root, to which Apache is automatically resolving any URL paths beginning with `/wiki/`.

One workaround would be to move your rewrite rules to the main Apache config where they'll run before any such mapping is done; another, more straightforward way would be to just change the first rewrite rule above to:

```
# match the short URL of the page:
RewriteRule ^wiki\.phtml/Aaron_Swartz$ http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/ [R=301,L]
```

or even:

```
# match the short URL of the page:
RewriteRule ^wiki(\.phtml)?/Aaron_Swartz$ http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried this code, but when I go to http://wecheck.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz the page doesn't redirect. What's also weird is that when I comment out the pretty urls lines and only use the code you provided they still appear. Is there some kind of cache I am missing (I have disabled all the  mediawiki caches I can find and am acessing the page in incognito mode).

Comment: That's strange.  Looks like you're on Amazon EC2, so presumably you're running your own webserver instead of using shared hosting; maybe there's a global Apache config file that's overriding your .htaccess?

Comment: I have also changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in the virtual host directories, but still nothing.

Comment: Yes it's on EC2 but I don't think there's a global Apache config. It just seems to have the standard config files. All the server config is in a file called apache2.conf plus ports.conf and sites-enabled.conf

Comment: I finally managed to get a log file. I have posted it in the original question. The log file only uses the code from iimari Karonen, and does not include the pretty URL rewriting code, which is disabled.

Comment: Based on your log file, it looks like you have a `wiki.phtml` file in your webserver root, to which Apache is automatically resolving any URL paths beginning with `/wiki/`. One workaround would be to move your rewrite rules to the main Apache config where it runs before such mapping is done; another, more straightforward way would be to just change the regexp `^wiki/Aaron_Swartz$` to `^wiki\.phtml/Aaron_Swartz$` (or even `^wiki(\.phtml)?/Aaron_Swartz$`).

Comment: No problem. Ps. If this answer solved your problem, could you please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) by clicking the check mark icon to the left of it? Besides giving both of us a bit of rep, it also stops this question from being listed as unanswered.